# Sed command to fetch particular string from full string

Tags: sed

I've got a file which contains lot of strings like below input.
Need to extract the below output and process it further.

Input:

```
History={ExecAt=[2013-05-03 03:00:20,2013-05-03 03:00:23,2013-05-03 03:00:26],MId=["msgId3","msgId4","msgId5"]};
```

Output should be:

```
MId=["msgId3","msgId4","msgId5"]
```

using (sed 's/^.*,MId=/MId/') command i got the output like MId=["msgId3","msgId4","msgId5"]};
but still wanted the exact output (need to remove last 2 special chars }; here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sed 's/.*\(MId=.*\)\}.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports the `-o` option, you can use it rather than `sed`:

```
grep -o 'MId=\[[^]]\+\]'
```

Using the same regex in `sed` works fine, just remove anything before and after:

```
sed -e 's/.*\(MId=\[[^]]\+\]\).*/\1/'
```